# Modify XML from the command line

Tags: xml, powershell, command-line, windows-7, cmd

I have a xml-file with a structure as following and I would like to edit this file from the command line.

```
<server>
    <service>
        <Connector port="8080" password="password1234"/>
    </service>
</server>
```

I would like to change the password or the port-number.

Does cmd provide this option or do I need an extra tool? I know PowerShell can do it but that's not the best solution for me. (Besides I didn't get it run with powershell :( ).

It would be also ok to search for "password1234" and replace it, because there is a default password in my file which is always the same and this must be replaced.

Comment: You can make the port and password parameters %1 %2.

Comment: Sorry, can you describe how to do it a bit more detailed?
Besides: It's not necessary to geh the port or the password value. It would be also ok to search for "password1234" and replace it, because there is a default password in my file which is always the same and this must be replaced.

Comment: I found some solutions for the for /f command, but this doesn't include the replacement :(

Comment: you might get  more eyes on your problem by including a tag for your OS (I guessing Windows7(8?)). Note the # of followers on each of your tags. `xml` people will want you to install `xmlstarlet`, but then you'd have to learn that too. Search/Replace for password1234 sounds like the "good enough" approach for this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Good to have added Powershell. That changes the game significantly. Did you try search here for `search replace [powershell]`. I would expect quite a few solutions and I'm surprised that no PS users have offered some ideas. Read thru a few highly rated PS (with XML) question/questions and see if there is any additional info  you need to add to make your question stand out.   Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Error: Method invocation...doesn't contain a method named 'replace'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335614/powershell-error-method-invocation-doesnt-contain-a-method-named-replace)

Comment: Got a solution via Powershell here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335614/powershell-error-method-invocation-doesnt-contain-a-method-named-replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To demonstrate one method I use let first create the xml file in your example:

Define a Variable for the XML Filename

```
$xmlFile = "C:\temp\myconfig.xml"
```

Define an XML String to save to the file

```
$xmlFromString = [xml]@"
<server>
<service>
<Connector port="8080" password="password1234"/>
</service>
</server>
"@
```

Save the xml contents to the file

```
$xmlFromString.Save($xmlFile)
```

Resulting file content

```
Get-Content -Path $xmlFile
```

> ```
> <server>
>   <service>
>     <Connector port="8080" password="password1234" />
>   </service>
> </server>
> ```

Here is the PowerShell code to change the values
Get XML content from file

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $xmlFile)
```

Finds the Element / Node and change the attribute values

```
$node = $xml.selectSingleNode('//server/service/Connector')
$node.port = "9090"
$node.password = "MyNewPassord4321"
```

Save the XML Contents Back out

```
$xml.Save($xmlFile)
```

Results

```
Get-Content -Path $xmlFile
```

> ```
> <server>
>   <service>
>     <Connector port="9090" password="MyNewPassord4321" />
>   </service>
> </server>
> ```

Save the commands to a PowerShell ps1 file and execute/run it via PowerShell.

We'll need additional details on what exactly your trying to accomplish such as:

- What rights will the user / account running the script has?
- Where will the script be running from? Local PC or server?
- One or multiple servers/work stations?
- Executed via Windows Scheduler Task?

Hope that was helpful. - Brooks