find and replace number after specific string in xml using regular expression
I have an xml payload as shown below.  I need to be able to find the property "ACME Account", and then the next value property value, replace the number with a new number.  So in the example below, replace 440228 with another number 482661.  The original number can be any number and never be the same, so that is why I have to search on the "ACME Account" property.  I have about 200 files with different account numbers that I will need to run a batch using my xml editor, but I just can't figure out the find and replace regular expressions.
    <Object type="TDM_Item_CustomData">
      <Property name="CustomDataID" value="CDA87DA35FA35g6jC7BA44F63B075A1612"/>
      <Property name="OrderID" value="180763_6210"/>
      <Property name="FieldID" value="ACME_account"/>
      <Property name="FieldCaption" value="ACME Account"/>
      <Property name="Value" value="440228"/>
      <Property name="Kind" value="cdkPublic"/>
    </Object>


Never handle XML/HTML with regular expressions, use proper tools like bash utilities, python, etc. Please indicate which are available to you.

I don't have any of those utilities.  I have a few different editors like Notepad++, EditPlus, etc.

May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443225/2834978

You can use XSLT for your task. Notepad++ has XML Tools plug-in that supports XSLT
